# Getting probablity of an event given a conditional probality

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given

```
P(A|B)
P(not A| not B)
P(B)
```

I can find out

```
P(A | not B) = 1 -P(not A| not B)
P(A AND B) = P(A|B) * P(B)
P(A AND B) = P(B|A) * P(A)
```

Can I get **P(A)**?

Comment: This question is more appropriate on math.stackexchange. This site is primarily focused on statistics and statistical research.

Comment: Probability is crucial to Statistics, for me this is a legit question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Let $S$ denote a sample space. Let $A$ and $B$ denote two events of $S$ such that 
\begin{align*}
P(A \, | \, B) &= \alpha \\[5pt]
P\big( \, \overline{A} \, | \, \overline{B} \big) &= \beta \\[5pt]
P(B) = \gamma &\neq 0
\end{align*}

where I am using $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ for the complement of $A$ and $B$, respectively. In other words, not $A$ and not $B$.

Then by the Law of Total Probability:

\begin{align*}
P(A) &= P(A \cap B) + P\big( \, A \cap \overline{B} \, \big) \\[8pt]
&= P(B) \, P\big(\,A \, | \, B\,\big) + P\big(\, \overline{B} \, \big) P\big(\, A \, | \, \overline{B}\,\big) \\[8pt]
&= \gamma \alpha + (1-\gamma) \big[1-P\big(\, \overline{A} \, | \, \overline{B} \, \big)\big] \\[8pt]
&= \alpha \gamma + (1-\gamma)(1-\beta)
\end{align*}